# Is there a booking app or site that lets you specify your gender for shared dormitories?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, accommodation, mobile-apps

I've noticed that on booking sites and apps such as Agoda and Booking.com that let you book a bed in a shared room in a hostel, guesthouse, etc, have a kind of way to game the system that more accommodations are picking up on.

They know many people choose accommodation by price and the sites sort by the lowest price for the cheapest bed. So many have started discounting female only dorms to get their listing higher up in the listing, but other dorms are substantially more expensive.

This must be great for women travelling but I'm a man and it's tricky to go through each booking one by one to see if the low price is only for a female dorm or also applies to a dorm I can use. And keeping track of the actual price I would have to pay for each place can be hard to remember without taking notes.

So I'm wondering if there's another site where you can enter not just the dates and number of people and location, but also your gender to avoid being shown many places you won't be able to stay at, or get the advertised price at.

Comment: +1 this used to frustrate me SO much travelling solo.  Nowadays I've got the wife with me, but my goodness, it would have been useful.

Comment: "*the low price is only for a female dorm*".  Sound like gender discrimination to me.  Sue them into oblivion!!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[hostelworld.com](http://hostelworld.com) allows filtering rooms by gender:

[image]

Comment: Ah yes! Too bad the prices it finds are so much more expensive than Booking.com and Agoda in Japan and Korea these days. I don't know if that applies elsewhere in the world but I've stopped using it on this trip.

Comment: Can you use hostelworld to find the hostel and once decided on the hostel, book it through Booking.com, is that what you mean?

Comment: @kiradotee In general the cheapest place on site A doesn't have to be the cheapest place on site B.

Comment: @kiradotee I think the issue with that is that on Hostel World some hostels you can specify the dorm but if you went on to book through another site, even for the same hostel, you'd not be able to do that

Comment: @Bee on Hostelworld you can filter by dorms and then book that dorm. On Booking.com you can still find the hostel and book its "female only" or "male only" dorm, it mentions that. The problem was in Booking.com you need to check every single hostel to find out if they have "x only" dorm, whereas on Hostelworld they have a filter to just give you hostels with "x only" dorm.

Comment: @Bee So my proposed solution above was use Hostelworld to get a list of hostels with "x only" dorms and finalise the booking on Booking.com as it's cheaper and if you're clever there are ways to get cashback with Booking.com (not to mention their flexible cancellation policy where you can cancel for free). From my experience a lot of time the hostel I find on Hostelworld is also on Booking.com.

Comment: Where are the Intersex dorms?

Comment: Ah I see, I understand your proposal now. I don't like booking.com very much so tend not to use, didn't realise you could specify once you started the booking. @Ron to get an intersex dorm you tick "Mixed Dorm"